# Call Logs not getting CACHED_NAME

Tags: android, call, android-context, android-cursoradapter, android-cursor

I am trying to get list of all number from `CALL-LOGS` which are **NOT** in my contacts,

I am facing an `issue` when anyone who is in *my contacts* calls me.

Cursor "**c**" is returning that number because "`name`"(`CACHED_NAME`) is `null`".

But when I open `call-log` application and then again I open my `application`, that number is not returned as now ""name"(`CACHED_NAME`)" has value.

*Could I refresh data in call-logs from my application?*

I can build one `function` which can check if number exists or not in phone contact.

But how can I use this function with cursor-adapter. I tried using this function in bindview, but still blank element is created for that number. I would like to use `CusrorAdapter`.

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    pview = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_call, container, false);

    ListView lvCall = (ListView) pview.findViewById(R.id.lvCall);
    Uri uri = Uri.parse("content://call_log/calls");
    ContentResolver cr = getActivity().getContentResolver();
    **Cursor c = cr.query(uri, null, "name is null", null, "date DESC");**
    adapter = new CursorAdapter(getActivity().getBaseContext(), c) {

        @Override
        public View newView(Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup parent) {
            LayoutInflater li = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            return li.inflate(R.layout.call_list, parent, false);
        }

        @Override
        public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor) {

            **if (contactExists(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("NUMBER")))) {
                return;
            }**
            txt_call_number = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txt_call_number);
            txt_call_id = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txt_call_id);

            txt_call_number.setText(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("NUMBER")));
            txt_call_id.setText(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("_ID")).trim());

        }

    };

    lvCall.setAdapter(adapter);

    return pview;
}
```

Thanks

P.S. There can be some technical `error` or `missing code` in above sample code as I have just extracted required `code` from my `application`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't directly access the updated call log `CACHED_NAME' with your application.

```
public boolean contactExists(Context context, String number) {
           /// number is the phone number
          Uri lookupUri = Uri.withAppendedPath(
         PhoneLookup.CONTENT_FILTER_URI, 
         Uri.encode(number));
         String[] mPhoneNumberProjection = { PhoneLookup._ID, PhoneLookup.NUMBER, PhoneLookup.DISPLAY_NAME };
        Cursor cur = context.getContentResolver().query(lookupUri,mPhoneNumberProjection, null, null, null);
        try {
             if (cur.moveToFirst()) {
                return true;
             }
        } finally {
               if (cur != null)
               cur.close();
        }
  return false;
}
```

Now , You can check into `bindView` function.

```
        @Override
        public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor) {

            txt_call_number = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txt_call_number);
            txt_call_id = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txt_call_id);
            if (contactExists(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("NUMBER")))) {
                txt_call_number.setVisibility(View.GONE); 
                txt_call_id.setVisibility(View.GONE); 
                view.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                return;
            }else{
                txt_call_number.setText(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("NUMBER")));
                txt_call_id.setText(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("_ID")).trim());
            }  
        }
```

May this helps lot.

Happy coding...:-)

Comment: Yes. This will work. But I would like to do some other way.... not by setting visibility.